# window.href for all browser

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

How can i replace `window.href = "someurlhtml"` for firefox and IE support ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
window.location.href = "someurl";
```

Answer (score 11):

You use the location object:

```
window.location.href = 'some.html';
```

Or simply

```
location.href = 'some.html';
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also do something like this:

```
document.location.href = "some.html";
```

or

```
 document.location = "some.html";
```

Comment: document.location was deprecated in favour of window.location back around 1996, when Netscape Navigator 3 was released.